# Visual studio 2017 disable scroll beyond last line

Tags: visual-studio-2017, editor

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and it has this feature that allows you to scroll past the end of the file.

I want to disable it because it's making me literally crazy. I can't find any configuration option to disable this feature.

Is there any option to disable it, where can I find this option? if not, is there any hack to disable it?

Comment: The answer of that post isn't useful at all, not for me.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't have a satisfactory answer - it's still the same question, albeit for an older version of VS.

Comment: Ok, yes that's true.